# ParametricPlot Piecewise Bug

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a code where I wrote a piecewise function and did a parametric plot. However, there seems to be something wrong with the plot because there is an ***edge*** that appeared which should not be there since my piecewise function only consists of two parts, first it is going to go up and then become a flat straight line. How can I fix this?

```
d = 3;
ag = 6;
pg = 6;
wp = 10;
b1 = 0.1;
f[z_, zh_] := 1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1);
ar[z_?NumericQ, zsr_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{zr, zsrr, zhr}, {zr, zsrr, zhr} = Rationalize[{z, zsr, zh}, 0]; zr^d/Sqrt[f[zr, zhr] (zsrr^(2 d) - zr^(2 d))]]
tAQ[zsr_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{zsrr = Rationalize[zsr, 0]}, NIntegrate[ar[z, zsrr, zh], {z, 0, zsrr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp] + b1]
SAint[z_?NumericQ, zsr_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{zr, zsrr, zhr}, {zr, zsrr, zhr} = Rationalize[{z, zsr, zh}, 0]; (zsrr^d/(zr^d Sqrt[f[zr, zhr] (zsrr^(2 d) - zr^(2 d))])) - (zsrr^d/(zr^d Sqrt[(zsrr^(2 d) - zr^(2 d))]))]
SA[zsr_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{zsrr = Rationalize[zsr, 0]}, NIntegrate[SAint[z, zsrr, zh], {z, 0, zsrr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp]]

ParametricPlot[{tAQ[zsr, 1], Piecewise[{{SA[zsr, 1], zsr < 0.996987}, {SA[0.996987, 1], zsr > 0.996987}}]}, {zsr, 0, 3}, AspectRatio -> 3/4, AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 24], PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: The data is undersampled. Increase the `MaxRecursion` and/or `PlotPoints`, e.g., `MaxRecursion -> 3`

Comment: @BobHanlon Definitely worked! Although it takes a longer time.

Answer (score 2):

Not a bug. I don't go into deep of your uncommented code. The definition of `Piecewise` at `zsr== 0.996987` and the `WorkingPrecision` option and `{zsr, 0, 2}` help:

```
ParametricPlot[{tAQ[zsr, 1], Piecewise[{{SA[zsr, 1], zsr <= 0.996987}, {SA[0.996987, 1], 
 zsr > 0.996987}}]}, {zsr, 0, 2}, AspectRatio -> 3/4,  AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 24], 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 ImageSize -> Large, WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

[image]